# Why does the Rest Api of the PAC (2200) does not return Yearlyprofile, Monthlyprofile and Dailyprofile?

Tags: json, rest

I want to call the Rest Api for the PAC2200 from Siemens. A PDF manual can be found under [PAC Rest Api](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/109817085/sentron-pac-%E2%80%93-rest-api?dti=0&lc=de-DE). And I can get the INSTANT values and the OVERVIEW as json if I put http://device-url/data.json?type=OVERVIEW this for testing in a web browser. So this works. But on the page six of the pdf under point 1.7 the values I don't get. For example if I use it without the optional part with start and count like this http://device-url/data.json?type=MONTHLYPROFILE it does again return the INSTANT result. In the beginning of the pdf it is stated that not every device supports every query, but just putting in the device-url results in a webpage where a MONTHLYPROFILE is shown. So the information should be available.